# Authenticate AAD with multiple tenants

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-app-registration

I have a dotnet 7.0 application (web app) and I want to be able to authenticate users via SSO from any Azure AD tenant. After authentication at Azure, I want to see the user's email-address and/or some kind of unique user id.

I have created a new App Registration in the Azure portal, under Azure Active Directory. The App registration is associated with my MPN account with a publisher. And I have tried using both Supported account types: 'Multitenant' and 'Any Microsoft Account'.

I can successfully authenticate users from my own tenant. But when a user tries to authenticate with a foreign tenant, Azure throws an error to the user: `AADSTS50020: User account 'someuser@foreigndomain.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/' does not exist in tenant 'mydomain.com' and cannot access the application 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'(myapp) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.`

But I don't want to add users as external users in my own tenant, because I don't know all the users yet, and there will be too many. How can I get my application to authenticate users from foreign domains as well?

Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect; // nuget: Microsoft.Identity.Web
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web; // nuget: Microsoft.Identity.Web
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var authenticationBuilder = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
authenticationBuilder.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.MapGet("/", (ClaimsPrincipal user, HttpResponse response) => 
{
    response.ContentType = "text/html";
    if (user.Identity?.IsAuthenticated ?? false)
        return $"Hello {user.GetDisplayName()}. <a href='/logout'>Logout</a>.";
    else
        return $"Hello. You are not authenticated. Please <a href='login'>log in</a>.";
});
app.MapGet("/logout", async context =>
{
    await context.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    await context.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
});
app.MapGet("/login", [Authorize] (ClaimsPrincipal user, HttpResponse response) => response.Redirect("/"));
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.Run();
```

appsettings.json with values taken from the App registration in Azure AD:

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To authenticate multiple tenants,** create an Azure AD Application by selecting "*Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Microsoft Entra ID tenant - Multitenant)*":

[image]

For ***sample***, I used below authorize endpoint to authenticate Multitenant users:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I tried to authenticate other tenant user, **I got the same error** as below:

[image]

**The error usually occurs**, if the Azure AD Application is not configured as Multitenant or if you are passing the wrong sign-in URL to authenticate other tenant users.

> **Note** that: To authenticate multiple tenant users, you have to create Multitenant application and pass Sign-in URL as **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`** or need to pass **organizations** as value for the tenant id.

**Hence to resolve the error**, I modified the authorize endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

***The other tenant user is able to authenticate successfully:***

[image]

[image]

**To resolve the issue, modify the `appsettings.json` file by passing `organizations` for TenantID :**

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "mydomain.com",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "organizations",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

I am able to generate the **access token** via *Postman* by using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Error AADSTS50020 - User account from identity provider does not exist in tenant - Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist#solution-use-the-correct-sign-in-url)

Comment: Thank you. I was following up on leads where they say I should use the common endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`, but I didn't know how to do this. However, your suggestion to use `"TenantId": "organizations"` in the appsettings.json does the trick !

Comment: If you want to authenticate Multitenantu users and Microsoft personal account users then pass "TenantId": "common"